# creating two separate device file streams for riffa

Tags: driver, linux-device-driver, device-driver

How do I modify [riffa_driver.c](https://github.com/promach/riffa/blob/full_duplex/driver/linux/riffa_driver.c#L1595-L1626) to have two separate device nodes, that are `/dev/riffa_read` and `/dev/riffa_write` instead of just `/dev/riffa`

I have tried to modify [riffa_driver.c](https://gist.github.com/promach/7716ee8addcaa33fda140d74d1ad94d6#file-riffa_driver-c-L1681-L1691) as well as [riffa.c](https://gist.github.com/promach/4c1a8c0d13edfb991ecd1fc64417af69) but I faced the following error:

```
[119625.539302] Error: Driver 'riffa' is already registered, aborting...
[119625.539307] riffa: pci_module_register returned -16
```

However, I am now facing the above error when I try to load riffa.ko module. It seems to me that this is due to conflicting MAJOR_NUM as you can see in the /proc/device log below:

Could anyone advise ?

```
phung@UbuntuHW15:~/riffa$ cat /proc/devices
Character devices:
1 mem
4 /dev/vc/0
4 tty
4 ttyS
5 /dev/tty
5 /dev/console
5 /dev/ptmx
5 ttyprintk
6 lp
7 vcs
10 misc
13 input
21 sg
29 fb
89 i2c
99 ppdev
100 riffa_read
108 ppp
```

Comment: It seems that each kernel module is limited to single "register_chrdev()" call. Please correct me if I am wrong. Besides, please see https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/char/xillybus/xillybus_core.c#L1861 as well. This Xillybus kernel module has more than one /dev/ device nodes

Comment: You can have more than one `register_chrdev()` call, but they cannot use the same major device number.